# AOSP Build - when switching from eng to user or userdebug, data directory no longer created

Tags: android, makefile, android-4.4-kitkat, android-source, android-make

I am building AOSP for a custom device (let's call it mycustomdevice), and have successfully built, imaged and deployed an Engineering build (`TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng`).

However, when I try to do a build using either a `user` or `userdebug` build, the data directory is no longer created (`myAOSP/out/target/product/mycustomdevice/data`). Thus, there is also no `userdata.img` created.

I've done a full purge of the AOSP source directory (thus the `out` directory is purged too), and re-loaded source. I then perform a `lunch mycustomdevice-userdebug` (or mycustomdevice-user), and then run the `m` command. Nothing else has changed between `eng` and `user`/`userdebug`, and a repeat of the same steps with the build variant set as `eng` will result in the `data` directory being included again.

I can't find any documentation on the inclusion of the data directory. I understand from a training session I did several months ago that the data staging directory is optional. What should I do to ensure for all `TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT`s that the data directory gets created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just an outcome of the install target for a couple of test programs that are included in the -eng build. For example, in one of the test `.mk` files, the following lines exist:

```
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := eng tests
LOCAL_MODULE_PATH := $(TARGET_OUT_DATA)/nativebenchmark
```

When the `user` or `userdebug` builds are performed, the `LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS` settings (eng/tests) no longer match, and thus the output isn't put in the data directory. As there are no ouput to go in the `$(TARGET_OUT_DATA)` directory (which resolves to `myAOSP/out/target/product/mycustomdevice/data`). Thus, as there's no output, the directory is never created.

Note that the `$(TARGET_OUT_DATA)` is just a staging directory - and it doesn't mean that there will be no `/data` directory on the Android device. When the Android device itself first initializes, the `/data` directory is created based on instructions in the `myAOSP/system/core/rootdir/init.rc` file, which initialize the elements of the Android system.

In my case, there is a post-build step script that creates the image for all partitions, and bundles it up into a single image to be written in one go to an SD card. This script expects the data directory, even if it's empty. So to fix this problem, I simply had to create the `/data` directory like this:

```
~/myAOSP$ mkdir out/target/product/mycustomdevice/data
```